# ruby regex - how to match everything up till the character -

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

given a string as follow:

```
randomstring1-randomstring2-3df83eeff2
```

How can I use a ruby regex or some other ruby/rails friendly method to find everything up until the first dash -

In the example above that would be: **randomstring1**

Thanks

Answer (score 47):

You can use this pattern: `^[^\-]*`

Comment: Tsk...Extra backslash. :) Dash doesn't need to be escaped when it's the first character in a character class (the opening caret doesn't count as a character in the class, it's a class modifier, specifically meaning "Not" as in "Not any of these characters in this class"

Comment: @JBB, I agree, my habit... :-)

Comment: Could you explain why this works?  I didn't realize you could use the caret twice.

Comment: @Brad, 1st caret is "beginning of the string". `[^\-]` means any character except `-`.

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk Thanks, I understand the beginning of a string part but I don't understand how it's used twice here.  Does this mean that `[^\-]*` means any string that doesn't start with `-`?

Comment: @Brad,no, it will just grab first matching string. Try to remove the first `^`. In this case reges matches `randomstring1`, `randomstring2` and `3df83eeff2`

Answer (score 9):

```
mystring = "randomstring1-randomstring2-3df83eeff2"
firstPart = mystring[0, mystring.index("-")]
```

Otherwise, I think the best regex is @polishchuk's.

It matches from the beginning of the string, matches as many as possible of anything that is not a dash `-`.

Answer (score 7):

Using irb you can do this too:

```
>> a= "randomstring1-randomstring2-3df83eeff2"
=> "randomstring1-randomstring2-3df83eeff2"
>> a.split('-').first
=> "randomstring1"
>>
```

Answer (score 3):

For this situation, the index solution given by agent-j is probably better.  If you did want to use regular expressions, the following non-greedy (specified by the `?`) regex would grab it:

```
(^.*?)-
```

You can see it in [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/ncNgZBo6Lq).