# MongoDB aggregation with a wildcard in the group

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of build statistics in a MongoDB and I'm wondering if I can do a wildcard aggregation query on one of the fields.

Here is a sample document:

```
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("52deab2fe4b0a491abb54108"),
            "type" : "build",
            "time" : ISODate("2014-01-21T17:15:27.471Z"),
            "data" : {
                    "buildNumber" : 43,
                    "buildDuration" : 997308,
                    "buildProjectName" : "Mobile_February",
                    "branch" : "FEB"
                    "buildResult" : "SUCCESS"
            }
    }
```

I have this query which will give me the average build duration by date and branch:

```
    db.builds.aggregate([
        { $group: { 
            _id: { 
                month: { $month: "$time" },
                day: { $dayOfMonth: "$time" },
                year: { $year: "$time" }, 
                branch: "$data.branch", 
            },
            buildDuration: { $avg: "$data.buildDuration" } 
        } },
        { $sort: { "_id.year": 1, "_id.month": 1, "_id.day": 1, "_id.branch": 1 } }
    ])
```

We have several of the same type of build jobs - one per month.  There is a Mobile_February, Mobile_March, etc.  We have the same standard for our other jobs as well...OtherJob_February, OtherJob_March, etc.

What I'd like to know is whether there is a particular type of job that runs longer or shorter.  This would mean that instead of grouping on the branch I would group on the buildProjectName, but it would have to be a wildcard search to bring back groupings of Mobile_* and OtherJob_*

Is this possible with MongoDB?  One solution would be to add a new element name - something like "jobType": "Mobile", but that seems wasteful if there is a way MongoDB could do it with the existing data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The MongoDB aggregation framework has the [$substr-operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/#exp._S_substr) which returns a fixed-length part of a string. It's a bit of a hack, but it would allow you to group based on the first x characters of the value.

```
db.builds.aggregate([
    { $group: { 
        _id: { 
            month: { $month: "$time" },
            day: { $dayOfMonth: "$time" },
            year: { $year: "$time" }, 
            branch: "$data.branch", 
            jobType: { $substr: [ "$data.buildProjectName", 0, 6] } // <--
        },
        buildDuration: { $avg: "$data.buildDuration" } 
    } },
    { $sort: { "_id.year": 1, "_id.month": 1, "_id.day": 1, "_id.branch": 1 } }
])
```

This would create two additional groupings "JobType", in this case "Mobile" and "OtherJ"

Comment: I think this would work if the first part of our job names were similar or the same size, but unfortunately they vary widely in length.

Comment: Would it be possible to do something with substring and regex?  Ie: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538884/ruby-regex-how-to-match-everything-up-till-the-character

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your job types are at least 6 characters long, you could use the [$substr](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/#exp._S_substr) operator to extract the first 6 characters and group by that field.  Example:

```
> db.test.aggregate([{$project:{type:{$substr:["$data.buildProjectName", 0, 6]}}}])
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("52deab2fe4b0a491abb54108"),
                        "type" : "Mobile"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("52deab2fe4b0a491abb54109"),
                        "type" : "OtherJ"
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```